# Remote db connection issues

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am trying to log into mysql using SSH using this command:

```
mysql -u username -p -h hostname
```

Where 'username' and 'hostname' and placeholders for the real params. However, the above gives an error :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'vps-xxxxxx.xxxx.com' (using password: YES)
```

Why is it appending the "@vps-xx...." with the remote server username?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am logging into a REMOTE MySQL server....not localhost....

Answer (score 0):

Place this on root

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with the grant options;
```

[Privileges Provided by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_all)

***Once you have finalized the permissions*** that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

---

### How To Grant Different User Permissions

Here is a short list of other common possible permissions that users can enjoy.

1. `ALL PRIVILEGES`- as we saw previously, this would allow a MySQL
   user all access to a designated database (or if no database is
   selected, across the system)
2. `CREATE`- allows them to create new tables or databases
3. `DROP`- allows them to them to delete tables or databases
4. `DELETE`- allows them to delete rows from tables
5. `INSERT`- allows them to insert rows into tables
6. `SELECT`- allows them to use the Select command to read through
   databases
7. `UPDATE`- allow them to update table rows
8. `GRANT OPTION`- allows them to grant or remove other users'
   privileges

Comment: I did all the above and the error remains! The VPS is appending "@vps-xx...." with the username for some reason.